# Export Csv Output file to Desktop in Rundeck

Tags: api, csv, rundeck

I am calling a API URL and storing the output in Csv file as below, since URL is run on a server, it stores the csv file in Server, i want this to be downloaded locally in Desktop when run in Rundeck

Code:

```
import re
import json
import warnings
import urllib.request
import csv

warnings.filterwarnings('ignore', message='Unverified HTTPS request')

url = "http://lappmachine.server:4450/api/35/project/ProjectName01/executions"
headers = {
  'Accept': 'application/json',
  'X-Rundeck-Auth-Token': '#Tokens here#'
}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers, verify = False)
#print(response.text.encode('utf8'))

response_value = response.json()
response_value = json.dumps(response_value)
resp = json.loads(response_value)
with open('execute.csv','w') as executeData:
i = resp['executions']

res_list = []
with open('ExecOutput.csv','w') as writer:
    for a in i:

        try:
            if (a['id']==0):
                print("Is empty")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("Job ID is : " + str(a['id'])) 
                res_list.append(str(a['id']))
               
        except KeyError:
            print("Job ID: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['project']==0):
                print("Project data not available")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("Project Name: "+a['project'])
                res_list.append(str(a['project']))
                
        except KeyError:
            print("Project Name: Key error issue, Check input again")

        try:
            if(a['name']):
                print("Job Name not available")
                res_list.append('')
            else:
                print("JobName: "+a['name'])
                res_list.append(str(str(a['name'])))
        except KeyError:
            print("JobName: key Error check again")
        
        writer.write(','.join(res_list) + '\n')
```

And the data in Csv comes in a single line, i would want this one below the other.

Csv Screenshot:
[image]

Expected in Csv:

[image]
kindly help, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can create a final step that puts the file on a Desktop path using python code, take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26028591/10426011).